# How to access the field value dynamically in the expression Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-if

I want to access the selected pick-list value to get the current record value dynamically but I don't know how to make that possible in AURA below I am giving the sample code please review it.

```
<lightning:card>
    <aura:iteration items = "{!v.pickListValuesList}" var = "picValues">
    <aura:iteration items = "{!v.allRecords}" var = "vv">
        <aura:if isTrue="{! vv.Active__c == picValues}">
        <p> --- {!vv.Name} ---{!vv.!v.selectedPicklist}==== {!picValues}    *****       {! v.selectedPicklist}  </p>      
        </aura:if>
      
</aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
    </lightning:card>
```

Here I Have written the active__c I want to achieve it dynamically from the selected picklist value picValues is the pick list values and the vv is the iterator of records is there any way to
get picklist field of current records
like --- {!vv.v.selectedpicklist} but this is wrong....

Comment: This isn't possible in Aura. You need to compile the data into an iterable form (Arrays).

Comment: I have only one Picklist value why I need to put that into the iterable???

Comment: Or can you just tell me how to achieve that iterable way?